# Windows 10 - Configure WiFi Direct via batch file without internet?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, hotspot

I think I may have initially posted this in the wrong section, hopefully I got it right this time...
I have an Intel AC 9260 in my laptop that no longer supports Soft AP/hostednetwork due to driver changes*, leaving me with only with the Windows 10 Hotspot feature as an option. However, this does not work without internet; you can't enable it without an active connection.

I haven't been able to locate a solution on google, and I'd like to know if it is possible to configure Hotspot/WiFi Direct via a batch file?

Here is what I was previously using, I'm not very good with batch files so please forgive any roughness:

```
@echo off
:settings
cls
echo This batch file will create a WiFi hotspot on your PC.
echo.
set /p ssid=Enter desired SSID:
cls
echo This batch file will create a WiFi hotspot on your PC.
echo.
set /p pass=Enter desired Password:
cls
:confirm
echo WiFi name will be: %ssid%
echo Password will be: %pass%
echo.
set /P AREYOUSURE=Are the above settings correct? [Y/N]
if /I "%AREYOUSURE%" NEQ "Y" (
    goto settings
) ELSE (
    goto hotspot
)
:hotspot
cls
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=%ssid% key=%pass% keyUsage=persistent
PING localhost -n 3 >NUL
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
if errorlevel 1 goto error
:pause
echo Hotspot started, press any key to shut it down.
pause
set /P CLOSE=Termanate hotspot? [Y/N]
if /I "%CLOSE%" NEQ "Y" (
    goto pause
) ELSE (
    goto close
)
:close
cls
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
echo Hotspot closed
goto end
:error
echo Operation failed.
:end
pause
```

I really appreciate any help on offer here.

*Intel article about the above mentioned driver changes: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000023257/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html

EDIT:
I've found some more info here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833873/enable-win10-inbuild-hotspot-by-cmd-batch-powershell

However this is getting further into the weeds than I've ever been. It seems this can be done via powershell, however I am still unsure if it can be done without an active internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

Windows has deprecated the old Soft AP and Ad-Hoc Wi-Fi networking options. Wi-Fi drivers have been removing the corresponding features, hence showing the dreaded "Hosted network supported: No" when queried with `netsh wlan show drivers`.

Instead, Windows now prefers Wi-Fi Direct for these scenarios. Wi-Fi devices and drivers can be checking for Wi-Fi Direct support with the command `>netsh wlan show wirelesscapabilities`. It seems Wi-Fi Direct is normally supported, particularly for the drivers where driver updates have removed the 'Hosted networks" support.

With the Wi-Fi direct support, Windows implement the new Hotspot features, but gives no easy to to set up a Soft AP for connecting directly via Wi-Fi to the Windows machine (as opposed a HotSpot which connects to the internet *through* the Windows machine.

However, the operating system support for Wi-Fi Direct and the exposed API still have all the features needed to set up a Soft AP. It's just not exposed as a direct `netsh` option anymore, which was the case previously. The key phrase to look for is 'Wi-Fi Direct Legacy AP Mode'.

There is a ["WiFiDirectLegacyAP" sample on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/WiFiDirectLegacyAP) which does the basics of setting up a SoftAP by assigning the SSID and passphrase, then starting the soft AP. The API goes further, allowing connections to be rejected, and various other options.

I have made a [copy of the sample as a new repo](https://github.com/govert/WiFiDirectLegacyAPDemo) and released rebuilt binaries for the sample, to make it a bit easier to just run.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: @Govert With the WiFiDirectLegacyAP sample, I see connections getting made and it seems like IPs are assigned...however, I cannot ping between machines.  Is this expected?   Is there another step required to communicate with a connected client?

Comment: By default, incoming pings are blocked by the Windows firewall. So to respond to pings you have to disable the firewall or enable the appropriate port and protocol.